# Pandas df.isnull().all() count across multiple files

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2000 csv files in a data set with 88 columns each:

```
      filenames = glob.glob('path\*.csv') 
       for f in filenames:            
          df = pd.read_csv(f, error_bad_lines = False)
          df = df.isnull().all()
```

This returns a series with the column title, and True if the entire column is missing. How can count the number of Trues(completely missing columns) across the entire dataset(2000 csv files) so I can express as a % how much data is missing on a per file basis?

If an entire column is missing per file, I would want to add 1 and keep a running total of that

Answer (score 1):

The way you've phrased it, you're getting the number of missing columns per dataset.

However, you can get the number of missing rows per column, you can modify that code and call this:

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

which will yield a count of missing rows per column. Something like:

`column1                     0
column2                     0
column3                     171
column4                     798
column5                     0
dtype: int64`

Simply calling `.sum()` again will give you the sum of missing observations.

The total number of cells in the data frame will be equal to the columns multiplied by rows, which you can calculate by calling this:

```
df.shape[0]*df.shape[1]
```

Which means you can calculate the missing percent by calling this:

```
total = df.shape[0]*df.shape[1]
missing = df.isnull().sum().sum()
percent = missing/float(total)
```

Just append those values to a list, so you can save them for reference later. Try something like this:

```
 misscount = [] 
 for f in filenames:            
      df = pd.read_csv(f, error_bad_lines = False)
      total = df.shape[0]*df.shape[1]
      missing = df.isnull().sum().sum()
      percent = missing/float(total)
      misscount.append(percent)
```

#### EDIT:

based on feedback in the comments:

"....I actually do want the number of columns missing per the entire dataset(2000 csv files)....So if an entire column is missing, I'd want to add that to a "missing variable" like yours and then divide by the length of the entire dataset(2000)."

So, in order to calculate the total number of columns for a given csv file, you can call this:

```
total =len(df.columns)
```

In order to calculate the total number of missing columns per csv file, you can call this:

```
missing = df.isnull().all().sum()
```

So the missing column percent per csv file can be calculated like this: 
    percent = missing/float(total)

But it sounds like you want a running tally. So let's use this loop:

```
colcount = 0
misscount = 0

for f in filenames:            
      df = pd.read_csv(f, error_bad_lines = False)
      colcount +=len(df.columns)
      misscount += df.isnull().all().sum()

percent = misscount/float(colcount)
```

Comment: Thanks Reid. I actually do want the number of columns missing per the entire dataset(2000 csv files), however. So if an entire column is missing, I'd want to add that to a "missing variable" like yours and then divide by the length of the entire dataset(2000).

Comment: Oh ok! Let me make some alterations.

Comment: Consider the shortened: `colcount += len(df.columns); ser = df.isnull().all(); missing += len(ser[ser == True])`

Comment: thanks @Parfait ! I think you made your edits at the same time as I did.